# Is$[0,1] \left\backslash\right. \left\{ 1/n :n \in \mathbb Z^+ \right\}$ compact if given the subspace topology?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

Let $[0,1] \left\backslash\right.  \left\{ 1/n :n \in \mathbb Z^+ \right\}$  be given the subspace topology. Is it compact or not ?

Comment: It's not even closed...

Comment: @akkkk: well, in the subspace topology it is :)

Comment: @Ilya, and that's exactly the reason why akkkk's comment is important (in fact, it answers the question): it isn't closed *in $\;\Bbb R\;$* and thus not compact, and since it has the inherited topology it isn't, again, compact.

Comment: @Timbuc: although that was my idea, I though that standalone such comment may be confusing

Comment: @Ilya Well, perhaps because of that it was *only* a comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not compact since, as indicated in the comments, if it were a compact subspace of the reals $\Bbb R$, then it would have to be closed (in $\Bbb R$), but it is not, so this already answers your question completely. Answer NO.

If you insist on a proof from first principles (directly with a specific open cover), here is one.
Consider the following cover of $X=[0,1]\setminus\Big\{ \dfrac 1n :n \in \mathbb Z^+ \Big\}$. Let ${\cal U}= \{(-1,1-\dfrac1n)\cap X:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$.
Then $\cal U$ is a relatively open cover of $X$ that has no finite subcover, hence $X$ is not compact.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on akkkk's comment: suppose $S=[0,1]\setminus\Big\{ \dfrac 1n :n \in \mathbb Z^+ \Big\}$ were compact as a space. Well, by akkkk's remark, it certainly isn't compact as a subspace of $\mathbb R$ by the [Heine-Borel theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem). Derive a contradiction!

Hint 1:

> Any open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $S$ in $\mathbb R$ induces an open cover $\{U_\alpha\cap S\}$ of $S$ in the subspace topology.

Hint 2:

> Since $S$ is assumed to be compact as a space, we can find a finite subcover $\{U_1\cap S, \ldots U_t\cap S\}$ such that $\bigcup_1^t(U_s\cap S)=S$.

Hint 3:

> Hence we can find a finite subcover $\{U_1, \ldots U_t\}$ such that $S\subset \bigcup_1^tU_s$ for ANY open cover of $S$. This is a contradiction!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $x_n=1-\frac{1}{2n}$ in $S=[0,1]\setminus \{\frac{1}{n}\}$  which converges to $1$ Hence $S$ is not closed